# Why does JavaScript sometimes function not work when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript voting system that has three buttons:

Vote Up, clear, and Vote Down

When I clicked the Vote Up button, it stays in zero. I have to press the Vote Up button several times to get it to vote up. Same with Vote down. When I pressed Clear, it does nothing.
Here is what I've done:

1. Assign function to Vote Up, and Vote Down and clear:

```
<button onclick="voteup()">
Vote Up
</button>
<button onclick="votedown()">
Vote Down
</button>
<button onclick="clear()">
Clear
</button>
```

2. Making a paragraph to display the result:

```
<p Id="vote">
You have 0 votes
</p>
```

3. Creating a global variable so I can access the variable on future functions:

```
var a = 0;
```

4. Creating the vote up functions:

```
function voteup() {
var b = a++;
```

5. Display the result in voteup() function:

```
document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "You have" + ' ' + b + "votes";
}
```

6. Making the second function (votedown):

```
function votedown(){
var b = a --;
document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "You have" + ' ' + b + "votes";
}
```

7. Create the function for clear:

```
function clear() {
document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "Your votes has been cleared";
}
I set the variable out of the function so voteup and votedown functions can access the a variable. I can't understand this.
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = 0;

function voteup() {
  a++;
  document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "You have " + a + " votes";
}

function votedown() {
  a--;
  document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "You have " + a + " votes";
}

function clearVotes() {
  document.getElementById('vote').innerHTML = "You have 0 votes";
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = "Your votes has been cleared."
  div.style.color = "red";
  div.style.transition = "opacity 0.25s ease-out"
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  setTimeout(function() {
    div.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.remove()
    }, 1000)
  }, 3000)
  a = 0
}
```

```html
<button onclick="voteup()">
Vote Up
</button>
<button onclick="votedown()">
Vote Down
</button>
<button onclick="clearVotes()">
Clear
</button>
<p id="vote">
  You have 0 votes
</p>
```

Also, you forgot a dot between `document` and `getElementById` in one of them.

Comment: Hi, I don't know why variable b is causing the problem. Because I assigned the variable b to a. Is it the same? Please explain your answer!

Comment: You dont need the b variable at all

Comment: What I said made sense in my head, but not in words. That wasn't causing trouble literally - it was fine as it was. However, it was an unnecessarily variable prone to causing confusion. The actual culprit was the missing dot `.`.

Comment: Also the clear function did not work. I can't understand what we did wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

When using `a--` the value of `a` is returned *before* the subtraction operation is executed. Thus, `b` is set only to the current value of `a`.

If you’d like this subtraction operation to occur *prior* to when the value is returned into `b`, use the decrement operator as a prefix (`--a`) instead.

The difference in prefix vs postfix of the decrement shorthand operator is clearly documented on its [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

PS: it seems that clear is a reserved word that we cannot use as a function name

```js
var a = 0;
const pVote = document.getElementById('vote');

function voteup() {
  pVote.textContent = "You have " + ++a + " votes";
}
function votedown(){
  pVote.textContent = "You have " + --a + " votes";
}
function doClear() {
  a = 0
  pVote.textContent = "Your votes has been cleared";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="voteup()">  Vote Up  </button>
<button onclick="votedown()">  Vote Down  </button>
<button onclick="doClear()">  Clear </button>
<p id="vote">  You have 0 votes  </p>
```

my way...

```js
const p_vote = document.getElementById('vote')
  ,   btVote = document.getElementById('bt-vote')

var voteCount = 0

btVote.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button[data-op]')) return

  voteCount = eval(`${voteCount} ${e.target.dataset.op}`)

  p_vote.textContent = voteCount ? `You have ${voteCount} votes` : 'Your votes has been cleared'
  }
```

```css
#VoteBtns button { width : 10em; }
```

```html
  <div id="bt-vote">
    <button data-op="+ 1" > Vote Up </button>
    <button data-op="- 1" > Vote Down </button>
    <button data-op="* 0" > Clear </button>
  </div>

  <p Id="vote" >  You have 0 votes </p>
```